# Why workload does not show requests on Work manager which is applied to REST BS?

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c, osb

Oracle Service Bus version 12.2.1 and later

I have a workmanager created with min and max threads which I have applied to REST Business service dispatch policy. I am not sure if this is even working as I cannot monitor this in workload monitoring.

The workload monitoring shows requests for all the other Workmanagers (applied on SOAP BS / proxy service etc) , except the ones which are applied to REST BS. The count remains 0 for all requests executed for REST BS.

I am unable to find the reason. Please can someone confirm if this is a problem / is this even working using WM.

[image]

Here is what I can see in workload monitoring. The circled - 0 is the count for workmanager which is attached to REST Business service.

While other PS workmanager and other BS workmanagers have increased in count. I tested individually each BS and PS work managers, and then identified that only the Rest - BS Work manager is not updating the count.

Can someone try the same and test the workload monitoring and reply with the steps in case it is done differently than attaching Workmanager to SOAP business service or proxy service. As I noticed the same workmanager works if I apply to other business service which is not REST.